# Secondary key in Django template

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm passing company information and category information to a Django template page and I'd like to take a value from Company.companycategory and look up this id in another model CompanyCategory which returns a human readable string. Is there a way to do this within the template?

```
{% for company in company_list %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{company.companyname}}</td> <td>{{company.companypostcode}}</td> <td>{{company.key.id}}</td> 
    </tr>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So company.key.id is the id which I can use to look up records from the CompanyCategory model and I'm sending a list of categories. So I guess my only choice is to loop trough all categories looking for a match? Or is there a better way to do this?

here are the models as requested:

```
class CompanyCategory(db.Model):
    categoryname = db.StringProperty(required=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % (self.categoryname)

class Company(db.Model):
    companyurl = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companyname = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companydesc = db.TextProperty(required=False)
    companyaddress = db.PostalAddressProperty(required=False)
    companypostcode = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companyemail = db.EmailProperty(required=False)
    companycountry = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companyvalid = db.BooleanProperty()
    companyentrytime = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    companylatlong = db.GeoPtProperty()
    companycategory = db.ReferenceProperty(CompanyCategory, collection_name='compcategory')
```

Comment: How are you defining your models?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using vanilla django it seems like your models are related enough to warrant a `ForeignKey` relationship in which case you could just access the company category by something like `company.companycategory.name`

It appears that `ReferenceProperty` will give you similar functionality on appengine.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ReferenceProperty
allowing each company to reference a category and making it available by as a property.

If you can't create a reference property then I believe you will just have to look up the corresponding category in your view for each company or You can create a method on your model that will fetch this data for you, especially since this seems like it could be a common operation.  Decorating the method using `@property` should allow you to access it inside your templates.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using company.companycategory.name to get the name within the template i.e {{ company.companycategory.name }}, but I have not been able to get the name associated. I'm off now to look at decorators..

Comment: This is what I have in my Company class: `code` @property
 def catname(self):
  return self.companycategory.name
 companycategory = db.ReferenceProperty(CompanyCategory, collection_name='compcategory') `code` But I cannot seem to get the name of the category with the template as `code`{{company.catname}}`code`

Comment: @Androidian I believe you access it through `collect_name` which you set to `compcategory` and not the fieldname (`companycategory`).  Could you try `company.compcategory.categoryname`.  Also it wouldn't be `name` it would be `categoryname` (because that is what you defined in your `CompanyCategory` model. So either `company.compcategory.categoryname` or `company.companycategory.categoryname` one of those should work~

Comment: I have this working now with {{company.companycategory.categoryname}}. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @dm03514, I can access the real values and hence text without needing to a further looking up using `{{company.companycategory.categoryname}}`